# How to Fill Empty Space in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm working on creating a responsive grid layout using CSS Grid, where I have a series of grid items displayed in a grid container. I'm using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));` to automatically adjust the number of columns based on available space. Additionally, I have a specific grid item (the third one) that spans multiple columns using `grid-column-start: span 2;` and `grid-column-end: span 3;`.

However, in the layout, the third grid item leaves empty space in the grid where it spans. I want to fill this empty space with content or additional grid items. How can I achieve this using CSS Grid?

Here's a simplified version of my HTML and CSS:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```

I tried adjusting the CSS properties for the grid layout, such as grid-auto-columns, to see if they would automatically fill the empty space created by the third grid item. However, these properties didn't achieve the desired result.

My expectation was to find a solution within CSS Grid itself that would dynamically fill the empty space with content or additional grid items, ensuring a visually balanced layout. like this image: [image: Expected Layout]

Comment: I do not think you can do it in CSS only. Filling a grid with elements of different size all comes down to the knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). 
On the other hand you could just use some code to determine if there will be empty spaces and add new items accordingly (or increase the col span of some items).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your perspective! While I believe it's possible to achieve this using CSS alone, I appreciate your insight regarding handling empty spaces with code. I'll certainly look into integrating code solutions to adjust items as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `grid-auto-flow: dense`

> "dense" packing algorithm attempts to fill in holes earlier in the grid, if smaller items come up later. This may cause items to appear out-of-order, when doing so would fill in holes left by larger items.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```